# Haskell how to resolve this error: Unsupported extension: MultiWayIf

Tags: haskell, cabal

while trying to install the `friday` package, I got the error

```
Preprocessing library friday-0.2.2.0...

src/Vision/Detector/Edge.hs:3:14: Unsupported extension: MultiWayIf
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
friday-0.2.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How to resolve this error?

I am using ghc version 7.4.1 and

```
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: based on [release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-6-1.html), `MultiWayIf` extension was added in 7.6.1. so it will not work on ghc 7.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MultiWayIf was introduced in the 7.6 branch of GHC. You're going to have to upgrade the compiler or patch the library.